# django rest framework ModelSerializer post data error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

first, in **models.py**

```
class UserComment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    rate = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    createTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '<UserComment {%s %d}>' % (self.user.username, self.rate)
```

then, **serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', )

class UserCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = UserComment
```

**views.py**

```
class UserCommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserComment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserCommentSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, )

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.DATA, files=request.FILES)
        serializer.is_valid()
        print serializer.errors
        print serializer.data
        return super(UserCommentViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

then i post json data 
`{"user":{"id":"1","username":"watsy"},"rate":"5","description":"hello"}`

i think,it will work. and insert it to db, but i get errors.

`{"user": [{"username": ["User with this Username already exists."]}]}`
**>_<**, I have no idea.

Comment: In `UserCommentSerializer`  use `user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)`

Comment: @hcwhsa i tried, and then i got ```IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")``` error.

Comment: Try to pass: `{"user":"1", "rate":"5", "description":"hello"}`

Comment: @hcwhsa thanks. i try use ```user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()``` in ```UserCommentSerializer``` . it works.   
but i not when i get data from ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/apps/usercomments/``` i got ```{"user":1,"rate":5,"description":"hello world"}```  
I want to get data as ```{"user":{"id":1,"username":"watsy"},"rate":5,"description":"hello world"}```>_<

Comment: Okay, then add `depth = 1` in the `UserCommentSerializer` serializer. You should add this field in the `Meta` class. http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#specifying-nested-serialization

Comment: If that worked then I can post that as an answer so that you can accept it. That'll help future users as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make few changes to your serializer:

```
class UserCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = UserComment
        depth = 1
```

Now pass this JSON dict in your request:

```
{"user":"1", "rate":"5", "description":"hello"}
```

Comment: if i user read_only=True, when i pass the json, i got ```IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")```   
i add ```depth=1```, but i get the same json data as without it.